# Explanation for the second case that made contextlib.nested to be deprecated (Python documentation)

Tags: python

`context.nested` is deprecated, I'm trying to understand the rationale behind this and after reading the documentation for a quite long time, I couldn't see an example to make the second issue clear:

> Secondly, if the `__enter__()` method of one of the inner context managers raises an exception that is caught and suppressed by the `__exit__()` method of one of the outer context managers, this construct will raise `RuntimeError` rather than skipping the body of the `with` statement.

First what is the meaning of inner context managers and outer context managers here? What would this look like in code?

**Edit:**

From what I understood, I tried to deomonstrate the issue with code:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __enter__(*args):  
...             print("enter A")
...     def __exit__(*args): print("exit A"); return True
...

>>> class B:
...     def __enter__(*args): print("B __enter__") 
...     def __exit__(*args): raise Exception("spam")
...
>>> with nested(A(), B()): pass  # A() outer context, B() inner context? 
...
enter A
B __enter__
exit A
```

But this code doesn't raise `RuntimeError`?

Comment: *"what is the meaning of inner context managers and outer context managers here "* - `with outer_cm(...): with inner_cm(...): ...`?

Comment: Please consider my edit.

Comment: Which one of those `__enter__` methods are you expecting to raise an error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, My sincere apology. Though, been working all day long :-( now I realized that the issue is related to `__enter__` of the inner context!

Comment: ...do you still have a question, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you have the context manager `B` raising exception in the `__exit__` method.  But the quote describes the inner exception being raised by the `__enter__` method.  I was able to reproduce a `RuntimeError` by moving the raised exception to the `__enter__` method.

FWIW, the replacement for `contextlib.nested` is [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) in python 3.4+.  There is a [backport](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for python2.